# Download complete directory and subdirectory command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, ftp, command

I am using ftp 
and i tried these commands

```
1) mget -r /foldername
2)mget * 
3) mget *.*
```

But all of above commands downloading only files . not folder and subfolder.

Any idea ? how to download this

Comment: Use a tool like `rsync`

Comment: some ftp clients may support an `mget -r`, but it is not the usual case. `scp  -r user@host:/paths/to/get/* /local/dir/struct` however can do what you want, but you have to set up the `ssh` keys (fraught with it's own version problems). I think you'll need some security access for `rsync` as well, so better set those expectations that this won't be working in 15 mins ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) which, to my knowledge is the only FTP client that supports recursive get. Here is an example with the `ncftpget` command:

```
ncftpget -TRv -uusername -ppassword ftp.host.com /home/user/local_directory/ remote_directory
```

Comment: can i install ncftp into ubuntu azure machine

Comment: @HituBansal You should be able to install it on any Ubuntu distribution with `apt-get install ncftp`.

Comment: sudo ncftpget -TRv -u myusername -p mypassword ftp.myshost.co /var/www/subsites/audemo/ subdomains/au/httpdocs/

Comment: i tried above command, it displays 
NcFTPGet 3.2.5

usages and flags list

Comment: /var/www/subsites/audemo/  is my local server path

Comment: @HituBansal The command is correct (given that `/var/www/subsites/audemo/` is your local path) and it works with NcFTPGet 3.2.5. Do you type it exactly as you pasted it - `sudo ncftpget -TRv -u myusername -p mypassword ftp.myshost.co /var/www/subsites/audemo/ subdomains/au/httpdocs/`?